# How to update cells in csv one by one without knowing column names

Tags: powershell, csv

I try to replace some texts inside a csv like following:

```
$csv = Import-Csv $csvFileName -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
    $properties = $line | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $properties.Count;$i++)
    {
        $column = $properties[$i]
        $value = $line | Select -ExpandProperty $column.Name
        
        # Convert numbers with , as separator to . separator
        if ($value -match "^[+-]?(\d*\,)?\d+$")
        {
            $value = $value -replace ",", "."
            # HOW TO update the CSV cell with the new value here???
            # ???
        }
    }
}
$csv | Export-Csv $csvFileName -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

As you can see, I miss the line where I want to update the csv line's cell value with the new value => can someone tell me how I can do that?

Comment: You're looking to replace all `,` for `.` to all "cells" or do you want to target a specific column ?

Comment: all cells that do contain numbers only (may be different coulmns), there also exists cell containing dates which also include a ","... Otherwise I would read the file, replace the commas and save it but this is not a solution for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the regex you have in place will match the pattern you expect, you can simplify your code using 2 `foreach` loops, easier than a `for`. This method invokes the intrinsic [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject) member, available to all PowerShell objects.

```
$csv = Import-Csv $csvFileName -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($line in $csv) {
    foreach($property in $line.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Value -match "^[+-]?(\d*\,)?\d+$") {
            # regex operator not needed in this case
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Replace(",", ".")
        }
    }
}

$csv | Export-Csv ....
```

You can also do all process in pipeline (method above should be clearly faster, however this method is likely to be memory friendlier):

```
Import-Csv $csvFileName -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Value -match "^[+-]?(\d*\,)?\d+$") {
            # regex operator not needed in this case
            $property.Value = $property.Value.Replace(",", ".")
        }
    }
    $_ # => output this object
} | Export-Csv myexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks. This way of iterating a PSObject is nicer than what I did as well, thanks

Comment: @prom85 this is just an alternative, one of many, if you had the properties of your object in an array, in your inner loop you can loop over this array of properties and do something like `$line.$property = newValueHere`. (I thought it was worth showing that `PSObject` is a think in PS tho)